# What does << mean as a method name, like def <<(score)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been reading a book about Ruby and I don't understand what this method does, specifically, what does `<<` do when defined as a method like `def <<(score)`?

```
class ScoreKeeper
  def initialize
    @total_score = 0
    @count = 0
  end
  def <<(score)
    @total_score += score
    @count += 1
    self
  end
  def average
    fail "No scores" if @count == 0
    Float(@total_score) / @count
  end
end

scores = ScoreKeeper.new
scores << 10 << 20 << 40

puts "Average = #{scores.average}"
```

Comment: `<<` is the name of the method. It could be anything really.

Comment: Can we say this method could be called `.append`? Or eventually `.push`?

Answer (score 4):

It's method definition. From now on, you can do:

```
score_keeper = ScoreKeeper.new
score_keeper.<<(score)
```

or, a shorthand (syntax sugar for operator-like methods):

```
score_keeper << score
```

Comment: Why use << in this context instead of an english method name ?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I guess it's "appends" the score_keeper a score. That's the only logic I can see behind it. Similar to `Array#<<`. That said, I have no idea why the author would name it that.

Comment: I agree with @Cereal I think it's because of the similarity to the array method.  I'd find it confusing though.  Just seeing `scores << 10 << 20 << 40` I'd assume it was an array

Comment: @MichaelDurrant C++ makes extensive use of overloaded `<<` methods so it's familiar terrain for someone with that background.

Comment: i want to thank you all your comments were great, but last question, why this method autoexecute itself, i can`t call it,it works automatically?

Answer (score 2):

`<<` only appends something when called on certain classes of object: the ones for which it has been defined as a method, and where that method contains code to append things together.

The creators of Ruby decided that it should work for certain object types and not others.  For example, with a string, it will append the argument, but if the argument is not a string it will behave in a way which might not be predictable:

```
>> "foo" << "bar"
=> "foobar"
>> "foo" << "1"
=> "foo1"
>> "foo" << 1
=> "foo\001"
>> "foo" << 123
=> "foo{"
```

Similarly, when called on integers it behaves in a way which is actually quite puzzling:

```
>> 1 << 2
=> 4
>> 2 << 1
=> 4
>> 3 << 3
=> 24
>> 5 << 2
=> 20
>> 1 << 3
=> 8
```

This is just down to implementation, I.E., the decisions of the person writing the code.  With the integers, it's doing *something*, but I would need to go and look at the source code to see what.

So, `<<` has been **implemented** as a method for various classes of object.  You could override each of these to make it do something different, and you could add your own implementation to make it do something to objects which currently don't have that method.

Comment: On `Integer`s, it's the bit-shift operator. `some_int << n` shifts the 2's-complement binary representation of `some_int` by `n` bits to the left … or put another way: it *appends* `n` zero bits.

Comment: ah, nice one.  I didn't bother to actually look it up :)

Comment: It's kinda important to look up those things if you're going to talk about them rather than say their behavior is puzzling. `<<` with integers is a very standard behavior and `<<` is a standard operator for that operation.

Comment: Thought that "puzzling behaviour" was a joke. Turns out it's not.

Comment: thank you for your answers i appreciate it, last question, why this method autoexecute itself, it works automatically?

Comment: @theTinMan you're right of course, although in the context of my point, which is that different classes implement `<<` in different ways, i think it's ok to not have to explain everything.

Comment: @ArielP - what makes you say that it "autoexecutes itself"?  You define it and then you call it like any other method name.

Answer (score 0):

*In this context* (appending or aggregating data), `Operator <<` is an artifact leftover from C++ iostreams. It is commonly used for serializing data to streams. This part here:

```
def <<(score)
  @total_score += score
  @count += 1
  self # < this!
end
```

Means that the class instance will be returned when operator<< is applied, which allows you to `chain` another operation without typing any parentheses or method names. It is just syntactic sugar.

Perhaps it is used incorrectly as an aggregation operator instead of serialization or appending to container, that's why it is confusing.

Comment: It's not left over from C++ IO streams, `<<` with an IO stream is just one way it's been used over the years. In C it's a bit-shift operator, which preceded C++, so, if anything, it's a C "shift" operator.

Comment: thank you for answering, but last question, why this method autoexecute itself, it works automatically?

Comment: @theTinMan I know, in this context (appending data) it is left over from iostreams. Sorry for not being idiot-proof clear and incurring your scary -1 wrath. Better context next time.

Comment: @ArielP it is called returning self, which lets you call the class's methods again on the result of the expression which allows you to do "chaining"

Answer (score 0):

`<<` is generally referred to as the insertion operator, because it's used for inserting information into arrays, files, collections, etc.

The person who wrote the code chose to use this rather than a method because this class is acting a bit like a collection of scores.

It exists in a similar way to the addition operator, `+`, but because you don't see it in mathematics it looks odd. If the `ScoreKeeper` class was only working out `@total_score` (and not also `@count`) then you might define `+(score)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it push as ruby uses "Push" and "Pop" with arrays and... any objects, really.
So if I have a piece of code like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

a will be a Fixed Numbers array containing 1, 2, 3, 4 and if I use the following:

```
a << 5
```

5 will be "Pushed" into the array so the array would be now `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.